# SQL Server join two dates into one row

Tags: sql-server, merge, case

I have the following query:

```
 select 
     e.IdEmpleado,
     e.Cedula, 
     e.Nombre, 
     e.Apellido, 
     CASE mo.Sentido
        WHEN 'Entrada' THEN cast(mo.FechaHora as date)
     END Entrada,
     CASE mo.Sentido
        WHEN 'Salida' THEN cast(mo.FechaHora as date)
     END Salida
 from 
     BAMBA.dbo.EMPLEADO e
 left join 
     BAMBA.dbo.MARCACIONES_PARA_LIQUIDACION mo ON e.IdEmpleado = mo.IdEmpleado 
                                               AND CAST(mo.FechaHora AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-04-24' AND '2018-04-24'
 where 
     e.IdCentroCosto='14'
```

Which results in:

[image: Result of Query]

What I need to get is 'Entrada' and 'Salida' into one unique row

The two tables are linked by (`IdEmpleado`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select e.IdEmpleado, e.Cedula, e.Nombre, e.Apellido, 
       max(case when mo.Sentido = 'Entrada' then cast(mo.FechaHora as date)
           end) as Entrada,
       max(case when mo.Sentido = 'Salida' then cast(mo.FechaHora as date)
           end) as Salida
 from BAMBA.dbo.EMPLEADO e left join 
      BAMBA.dbo.MARCACIONES_PARA_LIQUIDACION mo
      ON e.IdEmpleado = mo.IdEmpleado AND
         CAST(mo.FechaHora AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-04-24' AND '2018-04-24'
where e.IdCentroCosto = 14 and
      mo.Sentido in ('Entrada', 'Salida')
group by e.IdEmpleado, e.Cedula, e.Nombre, e.Apellido
```

Comment: Would it still work if there are more than 2 records for a given id in the foreign key table?

Comment: I have been killing myself the whole day, this did the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use else after your case and put your second case inside the else.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017